# Graph and statistics multiple regression show different things

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interaction, graphical-model

I’ve run a multiple regression to find out if visual memory declines differenty for the autism group than for the controlgroup.

I did find a significant main effect of age, showing that with increasing age visual memory declines for both groups. However, memory declines the same for autism as for controls over age, so there was no significant interaction effect.

But when I graph my findings in a line graph to compare the two lines (autism vs. control), you can see that memory declines less for the autism group. This implies that autism is a sort of safeguard for visual memory decline.

Concluding: my p-values were not significant, showing a parallel development of memory over age, but my graph shows that autism protects for a significant memory decline compared to the control group.

My question is what can I conclude from these findings? Should I just stick with my non-significant p-values? Or should I also write down that the graph shows something else?

My hypothesis was that autism was a safeguard for visual memory decline. Can I conform or reject this hypothesis based on my inconsistent findings?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a graph represents the trends in your sample but not in your population. Also, I assume that the number of the controls is greater than the number of idividuals with ASD. Thus they have greater variance and there could be some influencial points that make the difference.
You should first find if there are any [influential points](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/20/lecture-20.pdf) in your regression model, using [HAC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich.pdf) in R or [UniODA](https://odajournal.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/v2a3.pdf). This will actually show you if your graph is manipulated by a small group of points.

Even if this is not the case, the difference that you clearly noticed through the graph seems to be random, according to the model and thus you have no statistical significance.

Also, you should consider change your method by applying a different set of tests to the idividuals if you are convinced that there is a safeguard.
Please provide us with more information about the method and the tools used to conduct the analysis in order for the answer to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Now that you point it out I definitely believe that my graph is manipulated by a small group of points. My controlgroup (N = 129) is indeed bigger than my autism group (N = 76). I was interested in subgroups as well, namely a 65+ subgroup and 30-64 years old subgroup. My 65+ subgroup consists of only 27 people, with N = 5 for autism and N = 22 for my controlgroup. I am aware of the fact that this is a extremely small sample size for my subgroup. So based on that: I believe I can assume my statistics are telling me the truth but not my graph?

Comment: Also, in my graph you can see that autism and control show a parallel decline over time till age 65, after age 65 the lines are still parallel but the line for autism lays way above the line for controls. Is this because of that small sample size for the 65+ subgroup?

Comment: Well the problem lies in your sample size. If you want to analyze the difference between the two subgroups you should consider a non parametric method like a Mann Whitney test for the medians. Then you should choose a larger subgroup (eg 20-40 years old) in order to explain it with regression.

Comment: Is there a non parametric method for a multiple regression or MANOVA? I already did run the mann whitney, but my supervisor didn’t agree with it, because he said it wasn’t a replacement for the MANOVA (I used the MANOVA for groupcomparisons). Also, I can’t choose a larger subgroup, I got this dataset from my supervisor and I’m already in the last phase of my thesis. The only thing I have to do is to write a discussion and conclusion. But what you’re saying might be an idea for future research. Do you agree with that?

Comment: But concluding: my graph is not reliable because the small sample size in the subgroups? So I can’t conclude that autism is a safeguard just because my graph says so. I need to stick with my statistics, concluding a parallel age-decline in visual memory for both groups. However because of the sample size problem, my statistics might me biased as well. So I would need to discuss this point in my thesis, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The Mann Whitney solution is just a test between two variables. Should you need a multivariable test consider using bootstraping or the friedman's test with the iman-davenport extension which is for nonparametric tests for N×N comparisons.

Comment: Yes your graph seems manipulated and your statistics are backing this hypothesis up. Surely I am not 100% sure unless I see the data, but it seems legit. My advice: do not try to predict classes with low amount of data. Focus on the class you have the most.

Comment: Thank you for help! This sure is usefull information and knowledge I can use for my thesis.